# Display another YouTube playlist as default playlist, instead of Uploads

Tags: youtube, video

Is it possible to display another playlist instead of *Uploads* on my YouTube channel?

I want to keep the current videos public, but move them in another playlist and feature other *new videos* and do not show the other ones, unless somebody goes to that playlist or finds them using the search feature.

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: If I understand it then, you should change videos to unlisted/private and include them in playlist so they will be found only in playlist. (untested)

Comment: That will work, for the playlist part, but they won't be visible anymore in the search results. I'd still like to keep them searchable, and public, but feature another playlist instead of Uploads, under the Videos tab.

Comment: then that won't be possible. YT atm doesn't have such feature to swap/change individual tabs